# Is there a faster/shorter way to initialize variables in a Rust struct?

Tags: rust

In the following example, I would much prefer to assign a value to each field in the struct in the declaration of the fields. Alternatively, it effectively takes one additional statement for each field to assign a value to the fields. All I want to be able to do is to assign default values when the struct is instantiated.

Is there a more succinct way of doing this?

```
struct cParams {
    iInsertMax: i64,
    iUpdateMax: i64,
    iDeleteMax: i64,
    iInstanceMax: i64,
    tFirstInstance: bool,
    tCreateTables: bool,
    tContinue: bool,
}

impl cParams {
    fn new() -> cParams {
        cParams {
            iInsertMax: -1,
            iUpdateMax: -1,
            iDeleteMax: -1,
            iInstanceMax: -1,
            tFirstInstance: false,
            tCreateTables: false,
            tContinue: false,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 314, accepted):

You can provide default values for your struct by implementing the `Default` trait. The `default` function would look like your current `new` function:

```
impl Default for cParams {
    fn default() -> cParams {
        cParams {
            iInsertMax: -1,
            iUpdateMax: -1,
            iDeleteMax: -1,
            iInstanceMax: -1,
            tFirstInstance: false,
            tCreateTables: false,
            tContinue: false,
        }
    }
}
```

You can then instantiate the struct by giving only the non-default values:

```
let p = cParams { iInsertMax: 10, ..Default::default() };
```

With some minor changes to your data structure, you can take advantage of an automatically derived default implementation. If you use `#[derive(Default)]` on a data structure, the compiler will automatically create a default function for you that fills each field with its default value. The default boolean value is false, the default integral value is 0.

An integer's default value being 0 is a problem here since you want the integer fields to be -1 by default. You could define a new type that implements a default value of -1 and use that instead of `i64` in your struct. (I haven't tested that, but it should work).

However, I'd suggest to slightly change your data structure and use `Option<i64>` instead of `i64`. I don't know the context of your code, but it looks like you're using the special value of -1 to represent the special meaning "infinite", or "there's no max". In Rust, we use an `Option` to represent an optionally present value. There's no need for a -1 hack. An option can be either `None` or `Some(x)` where x would be your `i64` here. It might even be an unsigned integer if -1 was the only negative value. The default `Option` value is `None`, so with the proposed changes, your code could look like this:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct cParams {
    iInsertMax: Option<u64>,
    iUpdateMax: Option<u64>,
    iDeleteMax: Option<u64>,
    iInstanceMax: Option<u64>,
    tFirstInstance: bool,
    tCreateTables: bool,
    tContinue: bool,
}

let p = cParams { iInsertMax: Some(10), ..Default::default() };
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick read, but I'll re-read to better-understand. The "natural" defaults that some languages use such as I believe zero, false, "", etc., would suit me. I do understand that there are wider implications than my small "problem" to solve. Ability to state eg. "iVal : i64 = 0", would solve my wider needs, but I guess that's not going to happen. The "#[deriving(Default)]" should solve most of my wants. I'm unsure why I used -1 in my test program, but it's not needed (historic). It would be very useful (IMHO) to be able to assign a value in situ where the field is defined.

Comment: @BrianOh, tangentially, the "default values for struct fields" (i.e. something like `struct Foo { val: i64 = 0 }`) has been proposed and so may appear in later versions.

Comment: It would be good if that were implemented IMO - "struct foo {....".   I made the changes as suggested by you, using the struct as written in my question and with the default. That certainly suits me better and is far more concise. Being unfamiliar with the syntax, one minor problem that I had was not knowing the syntax for ALL defaults. IE: I used "= cParams{iInsertMax : 10, ..Default::default()};", but I actually want "iInstanceMax" to also be a default. IMO it would be preferable for "#[deriving(Default)]" to be part of the struct, but I guess the alternative suits the compiler better.

Comment: To instantiate a struct with all defaults, try `let p: cParams = Default::default();`. Wether you implement the `Default` trait by yourself or let the compiler implement it by using `#[deriving(Default)]` should make no difference in how it is used.

Comment: Many thanks for that. IMHO the defaults should be the default. IE. I don't think it should be necessary to specify Default:default etc., etc. I also think that the fields should be able to be assigned a value where they are defined. That's just from my simple perspective, and I realize that Rust is designed to be safe, and that there is a much wider perspective than mine. When one is learning the language (or at least me), the current implementation seems a little cumbersome. Rust is not a simple language IMHO, and the more that can feasibly be done to simplify it the better for me at least.

Comment: @BrianOh: If you use `#[deriving(Default)]` then everything is defaulted for you. The only use of writing `Default::default()` manually is to specialize it for your case. So... the default is already the default.

Comment: I'd like to provide a default (null) value for a *mut u8 in a struct that I'm passing to FFI - know how to do that - it seems that it cannot be derived like the others.

Comment: Is it necessary to define defaults for all fields when implementing `Default` for a struct?

Comment: As @huon said, there are proposals to make this simpler with syntax simuilar to Python https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/struct-field-defaults/3412

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Zargony. As a Rust noob I was looking for how to do this and got as far as the `Default` docs but they fail to explain what (if any) values it provides as defaults https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html

Comment: Please note, using `Option<>` instead of `-1` for integer types has memory implications, in particular the size of the original struct with just `u64`s is `40` bytes, while the size of the struct with `Option`s is `72` bytes, ~2 times more... :(

Comment: It seems that doesn't work with private fields sadly, which makes it non-resistant to any change where private fields are added.

Answer (score 44):

nowadays, it is possible to do exactly what OP was asking 8 years ago

> to assign a value to each field in the struct in the declaration of
> the fields.

using [derivative](https://crates.io/crates/derivative) crate:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#![allow(non_camel_case_types)]

use derivative::Derivative;

#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Debug, Default)]
struct cParams {
    #[derivative(Default(value = "-1"))]
    iInsertMax: i64,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "-1"))]
    iUpdateMax: i64,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "-1"))]
    iDeleteMax: i64,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "-1"))]
    iInstanceMax: i64,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "false"))]
    tFirstInstance: bool,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "false"))]
    tCreateTables: bool,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "false"))]
    tContinue: bool,
}

fn main() {
    println!("cParams: {:?}", cParams::default());
}
```

Also, it is not necessary to define default falsy values for booleans in this way because `Default` will set them to this value anyway

Comment: It would be nice to see something like that in the standard library one day.

Comment: @at54321 Hopefully, not, at least not with this syntax. This code looks so ugly and verbose (in my opinion). If one has to do this, then it's a lot better just to implement `Default`. No need to clutter the language with this stuff, otherwise soon Rust would look like C++, which would be a terrible idea. It's better it remains as a crate and people use it if they want it.