# How do I initialize defaults in a rust struct, somethign wrong with what I am doing

Tags: rust

I have looked at other questions :)

Like [Is there a faster/shorter way to initialize variables in a Rust struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650265/is-there-a-faster-shorter-way-to-initialize-variables-in-a-rust-struct)

I also see this in other help answers and docs.  But the code below that matches the pattern offered does not compile. :|. what do I do ?

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Foo2 {
    pub name: String,
    pub test_int: i32,
}

impl Default for Foo2 {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Foo2 {
            name: "Default Name".to_string(),
            test_int: 999,
        }
    }
}

impl Foo2 {
    pub fn print2(&self) {
        println!("Print name: \"{}\" int: {}", self.name, self.test_int );
    }
}


fn foo2_test() {

    let f2 = Foo2 {
        test_int: 1234,
        ..Foo2::Default::default()
    };
    f2.print2();
}
```

I get this error: ( I am using the stable build )

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::default::Default` for type `Foo2`
   --> src/init_test.rs:99:10
    |
99  | #[derive(Default)]
    |          ^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Foo2`
...
106 | impl Default for Foo2 {
    | --------------------- first implementation here
    |
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Default` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

When I comment out the:

```
#[derive(Default)]
```

I get another error:

```
    error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
   --> src/init_test.rs:125:11
    |
125 |         ..Foo2::Default::default()
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
help: if there were a trait named `Example` with associated type `Default` implemented for `Foo2`, you could use the fully-qualified path
    |
125 |         ..<Foo2 as Example>::Default::default()
    |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#[derive(Default)]` is only used if you want the compiler to write the `Default::default` function for you. If you use `#[derive(Default)]`, you'll get a compiler-generated function that initializes `name` to an empty string and `test_int` to zero. Since this isn't what you want and you're providing your own `Default` implementation, simply remove the `#[derive(Default)]` line.

In general, you either `#[derive(...)]` a trait or you `impl` it, but never both.

---

Then, to call the implementation, you can just use the type name.

```
Foo2::default()
```

Or you can use the turbofish syntax.

```
<Foo2 as Default>::default()
```

Comment: When I comment that out I get another error: ( I'll add it to the question becaue that has formatting.  Also what I put in was a verbatim cut and paste from a pattern document, and the other question I referenced.

Comment: @peterk Please see my edit

Comment: OK - I see you can't use Type::Default::default()  when you specify a custom version.  But apparently only Type::default().  Not very consistent and ambigulously documented.

Comment: NOte: ia also works when I make the fn default() an "impl member" of the impl Foo2 itself and not in a impl Default for Foo2 {} - seems weird and inconsistent or the howtos I looked at are out of date ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. `Type::Default::default()` is not valid syntax and it never was (unless you're naming your packages with capital letters, which would be very nonstandard). I've never seen any official documentation indicating that syntax.

Comment: It was copied verbatim from other howto and answers.  Of course they were wrong in other respects as well :)

Comment: @peterk Note that the answer you linked in your question uses `Default::default()`, _not_ `Type::Default::default()`. Valid syntaxes are `Default::default()` if the compiler can autodetect the type, or `Type::default()` if you want/need to be explicit, or `<Type as Default>::default()` in case of ambiguity.

Comment: I am new to rust but I would think if it autodetected it would also take it explicitly stated.   I would think that "Default" would be an internal type to the type being "defaulted".  I think having the "trait" default() as a "static" "method" of the struct makes the most terse sense, since there aren't "constructor" overloads one has to have a separate way to initialize an object for each different type of initial input.

Comment: @peterk I think you're approaching Rust with a very Java mindset. You're trying to see everything as an object with methods and static methods and constructors. That's how Java works, but it's not how Rust works. You can shove a square peg into a round hole if you push hard enough, but it won't work as well. I suggest learning Rust with Rust paradigms, and not trying to fit everything into a mental model that it wasn't built for.

Comment: well we can divide it all into data blocks and functions.  But in initializing a data block I would assume there is a default that must be set to be safe and then the default overridable by explicit code to change the default.  And if a specific way of initializing the block (struct or tuple in rust I guess) was done one would want to factor that out into a separate set of declarations or actions.

Initializing to defaults I would think should be implicit and not require explicit statements, only the changes to defaults needing to be explicit when a new block is instantiated.

Comment: Anyway if there is a recommend for a good forum tolerant of smart people who have stupid questions, I should probably be there as this isn't touted as a way to discuss such things :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment: "_if it autodetected it would also take it explicitly stated_". It does take it explicitly stated, you just need to use the correct syntax. For autodetection the syntax is `Default::default()`, and for explicitly stated the syntax is `<Type as Default>::default()` or `Type::default()`.